# Why addEventListener doesn't work with id attribute when result is coming from API

Tags: javascript

All the accordions are opening and closing when I click the button. I know the issue that all buttons and panel have same class name but when I append increment number with the class name addEventlistener doesn't work.

When I use map or forEach function get error that "map is not a function".

Please help to understand.

HTML Code

```
  <style type="text/css">
  #sidebar p {
  display: none; 
}
</style>
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
```

JS Code:

```
    window.onload = function(){

//function send_with_ajax(){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject) {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // For IE 
            } catch(exception) {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // For IE 
            }
        } else {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        }
    } else {
        alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP Request...!");
    }
    xhr.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", true);    // Make sure file is in same server
    xhr.send(null);
     

    
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){ 
         if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){


       
       
        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        //console.log(data);
        var sidebar = document.querySelector("#sidebar");  
        
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){  
        // data.map(function(){ 
        sidebar.innerHTML += "<button class='accordion'>" + data[i].name + "</button>";
        sidebar.innerHTML += "<p class='panel'>" +  data[i].email + data[i].address.city + data[i].company.name + "</p><br/>";
               

        var accordion = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion" );
        var panel = document.querySelectorAll(".panel" );
              
        
        for (var a = 0; a < accordion.length; a++) {
         
            accordion[a].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
             
            
              this.classList.toggle("active");

              var panels = document.querySelectorAll(".panel" );
                for (var p = 0; p < panels.length; p++) {
                 console.log(panel[p]);

                  if (panel[p].style.display === "block") {
                        panel[p].style.display = "none";
                            } else {
                        panel[p].style.display = "block";
                    }

                } // p for loop ends here
            
            });     //accordian addEventListener        
             

          } // a for loop ends here

      }// i for loop ends here
       // }); 

      };   // readystate


   };      //      onreadystatechange



      

}// onload
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, but I don't see anything with an id attribute. What item should have the id and what's the id?

Comment: @user1599011: When I replace the class='accordion' with id='accordion"+i+"' it doesn't work

Comment: Then what does your `document.querySelectorAll()` selector look like? Do you get an error message? What specifically doesn't work when you use the id?

Comment: @user1599011 document.querySelectorAll() is returning all the <button> and <p>but all of them have same class name that's why when I click on one button all the <p> expand. I want to append an index to the class name so when I click on a button only its respected <p> should expand

Comment: Adding elements in a for loop like that, using innerHTML, is pretty demanding. You should create all buttons and panels in code using `createElement`, add the relevant code (listeners, style) to each element while creating them, and then append everything to the document. No need to first add them and then querySelect. That's two loops instead of one.

Comment: Can you add an example of how the json response looks like, so it's easier to reproduce your problem?

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` show?

Comment: Does `document.querySelectorAll("#yourID")` return the correct element?

Comment: @RickardElimää: 
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, name: "Leanne Graham", username: "Bret", email: "Sincere@april.biz", address: {…}, …}
1: {id: 2, name: "Ervin Howell", username: "Antonette", email: "Shanna@melissa.tv", address: {…}, …}
.
.
.
9: {id: 10, name: "Clementina DuBuque", username: "Moriah.Stanton", email: "Rey.Padberg@karina.biz", address: {…}, …}

Comment: @user1599011: Thats the problem that the all the class name is same "accordion" and "panel" and when I click on one accordion all the panel opens

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your issue is not with the event listener. Your event listener is working on each button as you expect. Your issue is with the p elements, all of them is changing at the same time because you loop through them and change the display for all of them with each click.

You can solve this problem with just a simple CSS to display only the p after the active button (which the class toggle is the only thing you need to do). The CSS selector you can use is the "+", meaning the direct sibling.

Here is an example using your code base:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  //function send_with_ajax(){
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      try {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // For IE
      } catch(exception) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // For IE
      }
    } else {
      xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  } else {
    alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP Request...!");
  }
  xhr.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", true);    // Make sure file is in same server
  xhr.send(null);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
      var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      //console.log(data);
      var sidebar = document.querySelector("#sidebar");
      for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        // data.map(function(){
        sidebar.innerHTML += "<button class='accordion'>" + data[i].name + "</button>";
        sidebar.innerHTML += "<p class='panel'>" +  data[i].email + data[i].address.city + data[i].company.name + "</p>";

        var accordion = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion" );
        var panel = document.querySelectorAll(".panel" );

        for (var a = 0; a < accordion.length; a++) {
          accordion[a].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            this.classList.toggle("active");// why use 'this'
            /* The next lines are commented out, we will use CSS for the display */
            // var panels = document.querySelectorAll(".panel" );
            // for (var p = 0; p < panels.length; p++) {
            //   console.log(panel[p]);
            //   if (panel[p].style.display === "block") {
            //     panel[p].style.display = "none";
            //   } else {
            //     panel[p].style.display = "block";
            //   }
            // } // p for loop ends here
          });     //accordian addEventListener
        } // a for loop ends here
      }// i for loop ends here
       // });
    };   // readystate
  };      //      onreadystatechange
}// onload
```

```css
#sidebar p {
    display: none;
}

#sidebar .active + p {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```